# Laravel 5.2 Route Model Binding using methods and controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have configured my route the following way:

```
Route::model('terms', 'Term');
Route::resource('terms', 'TermController');
Route::bind('terms', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Term::whereId($value)->first();
});
```

This results in having automatically the term model available with default methods: edit, show, etc...

See below a code snippet from my controller:

```
public function update(Term $term) {
 //update term
}
```

However I want to extend my controller with a couple of new methods. So when I navigate to `terms/{term}/review` the `$term` is automatically injected into my controller. Is there any way to do this? Some like below?

```
Route::get('terms/{term}/review', function (App\Term $term) {
   use TermController@review;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the route module binding with `Route::bind` for the `terms` URI segment, so there's no need to specify that again in the additional route. As for the additional route, it should best be defined before the `Route::resource` (see [supplementing a resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers)).

You can write out your **routes** like this:

```
// Additional resource routes should be called before Resource::resource
Route::get('terms/{terms}/review', 'TermController@showReview');

// Init resource controller
Route::resource('terms', 'TermController');

// URI binding resolution for 'terms'
Route::bind('terms', function($value) {
    return App\Term::whereId($value)->first();
});
```

And then add the additional method to your **resource controller**:

```
public function showReview(\App\Term $term)
{
    dd($term); // $term is an instance of your App\Term.
}
```